# Самоудаление программы

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, bat

Необходимо чтобы программа при запуске осталась работать в оперативной памяти и удалила себя с жесткого диска. Пробовал через bat файл но выдает отказано в доступе. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

Вот как я пробовал через bat файл:

```
ofstream of("test.bat"); 
of << "@echo off\n:try" << endl; 
of << "del test1.exe" << endl; 
of << "if exists test1.exe goto try" << endl; 
of.close(); 
system("test.bat");
```

Comment: насколько я знаю, запущенную программу на винде так просто не удалишь. Для этого нужна сторонняя программа, её запускаешь, свою останавливаешь.

Comment: _осталась работать в оперативной памяти и удалила себя с жесткого диска_ - нельзя.

Comment: почему тогда на питоне получается? прописываю в начале команду на удаление файла, он удаляется, а программа продолжает дальше работать.

Comment: @Igor остаётся работать интерпретатор питона

Comment: а может можно создать независимый  процесс который удалил бы файл. ну родитель прекращает работу и дочерний спокойно удаляет файл.

Comment: "На питоне" вы удаляете *исходный текст* своей программы. И и на С++ все прекрасно получится, если вы будете удалять *исходный текст* своей программы на языке С++. Без проблем :) А вот активный executable удалить не получится.

Comment: Возможно создать виртуальную область в памяти куда скопировать exe, из нее запустить копию процесса, физически уничтожив с диска оригинал.

Comment: В современных ОС нет никакой "оперативной памяти", а есть только виртуальная память, в которую ваша программа *проецируется (подгружается)* на лету прямо из оригинального выполняемого файла по мере необходимости в процессе выполнения. Поэтому никаким осмысленным образом удалить выполняемый файл во время выполнения и при этом оставить программу "в оперативной памяти"  невозможно в принципе - даже понятия такого не существует.

Comment: В OS/2 была даже специальная функция API для такого — загрузить все в память и разлочить файл...

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы исполняемый файл не был заблокирован, необходимо, чтобы не было процессов, в которых он задействован. Т.е. нужно чтобы все экземпляры данной программы завершились.

Выбранный Вами способ вполне работоспособен. Вероятно, можно обойтись и без промежуточного командного файла, а удалять прямо из командной строки системному интерпретатору.
Оставшаяся часть проблемы - продолжающееся выполнение вашей программы.

Обращение к `system(...)` возвращает статус завершения интерпретатора. Т.е. ваша программа ожидает окончания выполнение вызванной команды, а не прекращает работу.

Это легко поправимо.

Кроме `system` есть ещё семейство функций `exec` и `spawn` (конкретные функции в семействах отличаются видом передаваемых `char`/`wchar` параметров, переменных окружения, использованием `PATH` для поиска и т.д. и т.п.).

Эти функции порождают новые процессы, но не блокируют выполнение (или завершение текущего). Функции семейства `exec`, наоборот, замещают текущий прцесс новым, т.е. ваша программа продолжит выполняться только тогда, когда вызов `exec` был неуспешным.
Если ошибки не были обнаружены, то `exec` и будет той точкой, в которой ваша программа будет остановлена. Дальнейший порядок выполнения деструкторов/atexit функций и т.п. может зависеть от релизации, а это потребует дополнительной проверки в ваших условиях.

В случае же использования `spawn` можно породить новый процесс-убийцу (например, процесс командного интерпретатора и передать командную строку для удаления), а выход из вызывающей программы произвести штатным образом. Если процесс-убийца просто подождёт некоторое время, а потом уже попытается удалить исполняемый файл породившего его процесса, то это будет иметь шансы на успех. Можно даже из процесса-убийцы принудительно завершить породивший процесс (или все процессы этого образа), а потом уже приступить к удалению исполняемого файла.

В Windows, вероятно, всё же потребуется некая дополнительная задержка после завершения работы программы до удаления.

Можно попытаться удалять из командного интерпретатора в следующем цикле:

1. небольшая пауза (ждём нормального завершения вызываюшей программы)
2. проверяется наличие исполняемого файла
3. выход, если нечего удалять
4. попытка удаления исполняемого файла
5. выход, если удалено успешно
6. попытка принудительного завершение вызвавшего процесса (или процессов)
7. пауза
8. возврат к шагу 2 (проверка наличия исполняемого файла лишней не будет)

Здесь приводится только примерный "рецепт", а не даётся готовое "лекарство".
Придётся повозиться с конкретным сценарием удаления, параметрами вызова интерпретатора.

В качестве интерпретатора, кстати, можно использовать и PowerShell, и Perl, и Python.