# Как деинсталляторы удаляют директории, в которых они находятся?

Tags: windows

Я вот вижу (по своему реестру), что все деинсталяторы лежат в папках, которые они удаляют. Но если попробовать сделать `thisDir.Delete(true /*recursively*/)`, то вылетит exception `Access to the path 'uninstaller.exe' is denied`. Ведь нельзя удалить файл, который выполняется. Есть вариант, что uninstaller может создать исполняемый файл (tmpUninstaller.exe) в какой-то временной директории, запустить его, tmpUninstaller.exe ждёт когда завершится оригинальный uninstaller,  зачищает всё и самоудаляется. Но, как по мне, это костыльный вариант решения поставленной задачи. Как же всё-таки uninstaller удаляет директорию в которой он находится?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Есть вариант, что uninstaller может создать исполняемый файл (tmpUninstaller.exe) в какой-то временной директории, запустить его, tmpUninstaller.exe ждёт когда завершится оригинальный uninstaller, зачищает всё и самоудаляется.

Правильно мыслите

[image: unistall]

Вот полная строка события из [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon):

```
8:26:29,1260988 unins000.exe    20396   Process Create  C:\Users\8CE3D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_iu14D2N.tmp    SUCCESS PID: 9672, Command line: "C:\Users\8CE3D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_iu14D2N.tmp" /SECONDPHASE="C:\Program Files (x86)\SHTRIH-M\DrvFR 4.13\unins000.exe" /FIRSTPHASEWND=$3B1228 /INITPROCWND=$680CC6
```

Есть и другие способы создания самоудаляющейся программы: [Самоудаление программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669564/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B)

> Но, как по мне, это костыльный вариант решения поставленной задачи. Как же всё-таки uninstaller удаляет директорию в которой он находится?

Инсталлятор программы в примере выше сделан с помощью Inno Setup, которая не использует модель [Windows Installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Msi/windows-installer-portal). Для инсталляторов, основанных на модели Windows Installer, необходимости в деинсталляторе как таковом вообще нет. При установке такой программы Windows Installer сохраняет ее MSI-пакет в каталоге `c:\windows\installer`. Для удаления программы достаточно вызвать msiexec с нужными параметрами, он загрузит сохраненный MSI, выполнит удаление, а затем удалит MSI.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к ответу от @MSDN.WhiteKnight стоит упомянуть полезную функцию WinAPI `MoveFileEx` с флагом `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`. В принципе, одной этой функции достаточно для удаления, и некоторые инсталляторы ее и используют для самоудаления анинсталлера. Проблема с ней только в том, что каталог программы при этом не удаляется (что мы и видим у некоторых приложений).

Для полного удаления вместе с каталогом используется двухступенчатый процесс, как описано в предыдущем ответе:

1. Записать в `Temp` программу (или батник) удаления.
2. Запустить ее, при этом удалялка должна уметь дожидаться выхода
   запустившего ее анисталлера.
3. Вызвать `MoveFileEx(szDeleterPath, NULL, MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);` для удаления после рестарта системы удалялки из `Temp`.
4. Выйти.

Вместо вызова `MoveFileEx` можно удалять через реестр. Для этого в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` нужно создать текстовое значение с произвольным именем (например, `DeleteMyApp`), и строкой `cmd /C del "путь_к_программе_удаления"`. При следующем рестарте Windows выполнит эту команду и удалит это значение из реестра.